# Homebrew 2 meter Yagi construction

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, yagi

Here is what I have

• A Baofeng Uv-82 transceiver

• A 1/2 inch 10 foot PVC pipe

• 3 1/4 inch x 36 inch Aluminum rods

• 2 1/4 inch x 48 inch Steel rods (I know they'll rust, it's just temporary to get it to work, I'll get aluminum later)

I don't have any coaxial cable (don't know the best type to get) and don't know how to match the impedance of the cable to the antenna.

So, what is everything else I need, and instructions on how to get this built and working. I'm sorry if I'm asking for too much, and I don't want to ask for you to "design" an antenna for me, I just want a bit of help.

[image]

Comment: So what do you want it to do (performance wise)? How do you expect to use it?

Comment: SIMPLEX to friends some distance away (20km +) and 2 meter amsats

Comment: Correction - less than 20 km (10-20)

Comment: You seem to realize that this question is *too broad*. Apologizing doesn't make it less broad; you need to ask a *specific* question. As it stands, the answer to this question is a book on antenna design.

Comment: It seems like I can never ask a good question on this site

Comment: @Skyler440 why don't you do some research on antenna design, and when you encounter a concept you don't understand, ask about *that*? For example, rather than asking *simple wire dipole help*, try asking *Why is the length of a dipole 468/frequency?* The former is a broad "fish for me" question and demonstrates very little research effort and is mostly helpful only to you. The latter is a specific "teach me how to fish" question that will be relevant for a large number of people in the future.

Comment: Wow, this gave me an idea. Now I know what to do with my old broken fishing pole!  It will make a great mast for a 440/2m satellite antenna -- complete with hand grip.

Answer (score 1):

You will find one decent design that will use the pieces you have in the article "[7 dB for 7 bucks](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/9304054.pdf)", by Nathan Loucks, WB0CMT, which has a basic construction as follows:

[image: Three element Yagi. 37-39" dipole near center, 40" reflector 16 inches from dipole, 35" director 20" from dipole.]

The article recommends that if your radio is further than 15 feet you'll want a good low loss cable such as RG-213.

While you have the parts for a larger Yagi, you indicate you want to use it for satellite communication, which will require it to be handheld as you track the satellite.  This is a great starter antenna that can be handheld without being too unwieldy, and while it has modest gain it should be enough for you to accomplish both your goals with very little work.

Note that the driven element is adjustable - you'll need to adjust that for the lowest SWR in order to accomplish your impedance matching.